# Why is this table not width 100%

Tags: html, css

I tried it on several browsers and my table is not 100% width. It seems to adjust to the content even though I set it to be width:100%. This is my url (which will look just the way I want it before you login): 
http://heliumscraper.com/en2/index.php?p=download
Try to login with username: "someuser" and pass "resuemos" (without the quotiation marks both) and you will see that the download page shows the semitransparent box (which is a table) smaller than it should. (I want it to be the same size as [here](http://heliumscraper.com/en2/index.php?p=home)). What am I missing?

**Edit:** I'm not concerned about the spaces of about 50 px on both left and right sides. I want that. I'm concerned about the small size of the semitransparent box **after** you login.

Comment: Can you extract just the HTML and CSS we need to see to help you?

Comment: I thought it was super easy to see it from the borwser. Problem is that it has php and lots of stuff.

Comment: well I can copy and paste the html but I think it would be a big waste of space since any browser can let you see it.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `width` attribute of the `table` element.  Instead, try to get it into CSS, where the behavior is more predictable.

Comment: Is that going to make the difference? I'll see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your website and used firebug on it. The problem is not with the table but with the "content-div" style. I dynamically changed the width of it to 100% and the table did stretch across the window. Hope this is helpful. Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: I meant div class='content-div' that surrounds your table.

Comment: I changed my content_div definition to width"100% but it messed up the whole thing, since it has borders it went over the right border and a bottom horizontal scrollbar appeared because the contents were bigger than the browser window

Comment: Yes, I see you have a 3em padding and margin. Can you try reducing the width percentage?

Comment: There is no elegant solution for full-width boxes (not before IE 6/7 die out and stuff like [box-sizing](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) or [box-orient/box-align](http://www.css3.info/introducing-the-flexible-box-layout-module/) can be used), but you could probably wrap `#content_div` in a div with 100% width, some margin or padding and no visual effect. 100% width for `#content_div` would then mean the inner width of the wrapper div (that is, page width minus wrapper margin/padding), and the border of `#content_div` would overflow to the wrapper's padding/margin and cause no problem.

Comment: Yes, I think that will work. @Jsoldi can you please try wrapping your content div with another 100% width container.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with anything. Both tables are 100% width
But, please note that, the browser window width is NOT the same for the two pages you are comparing.
One page has few contents, so no scrollbar. Other page has more contents, so browser scrollbar is added on the right side.

Comment: That's between home and download but not between download and after log in

Answer (score 0):

in your content_div, do not use padding instead use margin-left and margin-top to align.

.content_div {
    border-style: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}